# Make text fill the screen inside edit text

Tags: android

I want my `EditText` , as well as the text i type inside, take the whole screen. but here, only EditText matches the parent, and the text inside doesn't

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/vector"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#50dddddd"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:maxWidth="5.0dip"
    android:minWidth="10.0dip"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:textColor="#424242"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Write File to Application SandBox"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Read File from Application SandBox"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/antivirus_btn2"
    android:text="  READ  "
    android:textColor="@drawable/antivirus_btn_text2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/antivirus_btn3"
    android:text="  SAVE  "
    android:textColor="@drawable/antivirus_btn_text3" />
```

Comment: you need to specify android:textsize for edittext

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read the following article [Using auto resize to fit EditText in Android](https://viksaaskool.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/using-auto-resize-to-fit-edittext-in-android/) 
There is exactly explained how you create such a control. And also the full code you can find there.

Comment: check this question i implemented it but can't figure out something http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892294/how-to-set-min-text-size-in-custom-edit-text