# How to set min text size in custom edit text?

Tags: android

I am using this custom EditText which resizes the text inside my EditText automatically. It works fine, however, the text gets way too tiny before it changes line. how do i set my min text size? so that it changes line only when text size reaches 12sp

```
public class FontFitTextView extends EditText {

// Attributes
private Paint mTestPaint;
private float defaultTextSize;

public FontFitTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
}

public FontFitTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    mTestPaint = new Paint();
    mTestPaint.set(this.getPaint());
    defaultTextSize = getTextSize();
}

/* Re size the font so the specified text fits in the text box
 * assuming the text box is the specified width.
 */
private void refitText(String text, int textWidth) {

    if (textWidth <= 0 || text.isEmpty())
        return;

    int targetWidth = textWidth - this.getPaddingLeft() - this.getPaddingRight();

    // this is most likely a non-relevant call
    if( targetWidth<=2 )
        return;

    // text already fits with the xml-defined font size?
    mTestPaint.set(this.getPaint());
    mTestPaint.setTextSize(defaultTextSize);
    if(mTestPaint.measureText(text) <= targetWidth) {
        this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, defaultTextSize);
        return;
    }

    // adjust text size using binary search for efficiency
    float hi = defaultTextSize;
    float lo = 2;
    final float threshold = 0.5f; // How close we have to be
    while (hi - lo > threshold) {
        float size = (hi + lo) / 2;
        mTestPaint.setTextSize(size);
        if(mTestPaint.measureText(text) >= targetWidth )
            hi = size; // too big
        else
            lo = size; // too small

    }

    // Use lo so that we undershoot rather than overshoot
    this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, lo);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    refitText(this.getText().toString(), parentWidth);
    this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, height);
}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start,
                             final int before, final int after) {
    refitText(text.toString(), this.getWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
        refitText(this.getText().toString(), w);
    }
}
```

}

```
<com.your.package.activity.widget.FontFitTextView
android:id="@+id/my_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="My Text"
android:textSize="60sp" />
```

Comment: Can you add your test xml pls

Comment: @KevinWallis done, please check the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change the value from `lo`

```
// adjust text size using binary search for efficiency
float hi = defaultTextSize;
float lo = 2;
```

For e.g.:

```
// adjust text size using binary search for efficiency
float minTextSize = defaultTextSize / 2;
float hi = defaultTextSize;
float lo = minTextSize;
```

Comment: how do i set min font size 12? your code works but it gets too small before it changes line

Comment: @Cassie I would set the `minTextSize` depending on the `defaultTextSize`. So when the default is 120 you could use 1/10 of it

Comment: thank you Kevin. BTW can you answer this ? i'm like stuck for 4 days and no luck :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897409/why-is-my-intent-not-working