# Why is my intent not working?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the `Equalizer` intent work on my app, I call my system's built in equalizer like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL");
if ((intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)) {
  // here is the changes  
  // REQUEST_CODE is an any integer value
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
} else {
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "device not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The problem in my code is that it is opening, however, it doesn't change the audio quality at all. No matter how much I fiddle with the knobs, sound remains the same.

Spottily also does the same, they are not using any class because the interface of equalizer changes with respect to Android Version.

What did i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `manifest` have you added the needed permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Check the following `manifest` as example: [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/MusicFX/+/f2f3fcd148769c5189c0d41c6ca85a8f14e6b534/AndroidManifest.xml)

Have you also tried to request the permissions see the following link (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: samsung, samsung, htc and htc

Comment: @Cassie I have added a link to my answer maybe you have to add a permission request when using Android 6.0+

Comment: i fixed it by- 1) detect if the device has FX app 2) if it has, launch the app, else, use equalizer class.

Comment: could you answer this question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066095/how-to-add-strings-to-text-file

Answer (score 0):

> Add this to your activity in your minifest  to open default equlizer

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_CONTENT_MUSIC" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: When I read the question correct the `Equalizer` is shown but there are no changes from the volume.