# How to add strings to text file?

Tags: android

I am trying to save each visited `URL` in a `.txt` file. It works fine, however, every new `URL` replaces the older one.

**1)** How do i add URL's (on top, Not bottom) ?

**2)** How do i add a one line space between each URL?

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    // don't hide URLBar on welcome screen

    // save to history.txt
    HistoryHelper file = new HistoryHelper(view.getContext());
    file.writeToSD(url.toString());
}
```

**HistoryHelper.java**

```
public class HistoryHelper {

    String TAG = "MyFile";
    Context context;

    public HistoryHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Boolean writeToSD(String text) {
        Boolean write_successful = false;
        File root = null;
        try {
            // check for SDcard
            root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Log.i(TAG, "path.." + root.getAbsolutePath());

            // check sdcard permission
            if (root.canWrite()) {
                File fileDir = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AVD/");
                fileDir.mkdirs();

                File file = new File(fileDir, "History.txt");
                FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
                out.write(text);
                out.close();
                write_successful = true;
                Toast.makeText(context, "success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR:---",
                    "Could not write file to SDCard" + e.getMessage());
            write_successful = false;
            Toast.makeText(context, "operation failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
        return write_successful;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open file in append mode

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter (file,  true) ;
```

Use BufferedWriter, you are opening file each time when URL get accessed.  Try to minimise disk i/O overhead.

Comment: what is "disk i/O overhead"?

Comment: For every URL accessed you are creating a new object of historyHelper and opens file each time,  so try to use one object and use that reference only

Comment: Like pointed out you could e.g. make the method `writeToSD` static and the `Toast` you could also create in the `onPageStarted` method depending on the return value of the `writeToSD` method. So it is easier reuse, maintain and you don't need to create a `HistoryHelper` object each time.