# How to make text fit entire TextBox?

Tags: java, textbox

I'm working on a simple calculator for Android devices.
I have some TextBoxes inside LinearLayouts, each with a weight of 1.
I set the text size of each of them to be 30dp.

My problem is that on tablets this text size is to small. On small smartphones the text is to big.
How can I make the text fit entire view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the following question: [How to set min text size in custom edit text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892294/how-to-set-min-text-size-in-custom-edit-text/37900583#37900583) There is a custom `EditText` which you could use.